# Is it possible to clone Linux software RAID 0 array with LVM on top to a single HDD?

Tags: backup, lvm, software-raid, cloning, raid0

I have 2 500GB HDD in 3 software RAID 0 arrays with LVM on top.

Both disks are partitioned: 
-MBR partition table 
-256 MB Physical volume for RAID 
-4 GB Physical volume for RAID 
-remaining 496 GB Physical volume for RAID

Is it possible to clone the array to a single 1TB HDD?
 
 
I am aware of migration and backup software like rsync, BackInTime, deja-dup, Aptik and similar. I am only interested in cloning.
 
 
If you need more information, please ask.

Answer (score 1):

It obviously does not make sense to use RAID 0 on a single drive. So you can simply create one large partition, make it a PV and then create LVs which are exactly the size as on the RAIDs. You cannot clone the LVM data because you cannot have two VGs with the same name.

Then you can use `dd` to clone the LV content.

Comment: `cat` will almost certainly be faster than `dd`